# How to settup django login in the header?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup user login in the header, that way, the user can login/logout at any point in the web. However I must have missunderstood the Django tutorials. I am kind of a newbie with Django and I am not entirely sure of how to accomplish this, so any help is welcome.

I would like to clarify also, that I do not wish to redirect to another template. If possible, just reload the current page with the user already authenticated.

I tried 2 things:

1. add `action="{% url 'sign_in' %}"`  in the header form
2. add `action="{% url 'accounts_login' %}"`  in the header form

And neither seems to work.

- My app name is 'web'
- My project name is 'core'

```
# core/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('rest/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include('web.urls'))
]
```

```
# web/urls.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.base),
    path('sign_in', views.sign_in, name='sign_in'),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='accounts_login')
]
```

```
# wev/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
import requests


def base(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)


def sign_in(request):
    if request.POST:
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            print(user)
            login(request, user)
            return base(request)
    return base(request)
```

```
<!-- base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            {% include 'header.html' %}
        </header>
        <main>
            {% block main %}
                Main content
            {% endblock %}
        </main>
        <footer>
            {% include 'footer.html' %}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- header.html -->
<!-- I am using bootstrap so i removed all extra divs an classes for readibility -->
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}!</p>
            <button>Sign out</button>
        {% else %}
            <button>Sign up</button>
            <button>Sign in</button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="bootstrapModal">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'accounts_login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div>
            <h5>Sign in</h5>
            <button type="button" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Password</label>
                <input name="password type="password" placeholder="Password" ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: to determined where the problem lies at can you check if the `if statement` sign_in worked when you login? for example try to print out a text on terminal inside the if statement

Comment: When you can "And neither seems to work," what do you mean?  Are you getting a traceback?  Is nothing happening when you click the sign in link?

Comment: just a guess but shouldn't your login form use `sign_in` URL instead of `accounts_login` ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen The ```if``` is working fine. Actually if I go to DjangoRest admin and log in, then if I come back to the base.html page, the welcome message appears just fine. @robline However if I try to loggin through my header template (with the forms action url set to accounts_login for example) I get redirected to that url, but without successfully being logged in.